# Domains with SSL on dokku

Tags: node.js, ssl, dokku

I have a NodeJS app on ubuntu EC2 with dokku. My domain is pointing on server with wildcard and I have a SSL certificate with wildcard as well. Some time ago I added keys to dokku in app/tls/. Back then I had two apps online, production and staging. The last created on dokku (created, deployed) was intercepting all requests to host so api.my.domain and api-stage.my.domain and blah and whatever. If I typed http:// then there was no redirect. Deadline was close so I wasn't fighting with it anymore and I just made production to be the one who intercepts everything. Today I had problems with deployment, I've seen rejects over and over. I've deleted some plugins including not used anywhere dokku-domains, restarted docker few times run this command:
sudo wget -O /etc/init/docker.conf https://raw.github.com/dotcloud/docker/master/contrib/init/upstart/docker.conf
and there was no rejects anymore but... all requests to host returns 502 Bad Gateway. and there was no rejects anymore but... all requests to host returns 502 Bad Gateway including those with green padlock. I remember that previously when app was during deployment there was some info about configuring SSL, now there is none. After deleting an app and creating from scratch there is no nginx.conf file and SSL doesn't work at all.

Comment: Wipe out the whole server, install everything from scratch and then promise yourself you never ever use dokku again. I worked with it for six months and I wouldn't recommend it to my worst enemy.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. So what do you currently use?

Comment: Project that I worked on stayed with dokku because won't be continued and the new one was sat up with amazon elasticbeanstalk. If I was going to use docker then I would take a look on https://flynn.io/, it looks promising.